# Implementation of pyfpdf on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

Some questions about pyfpdf on Google App Engine.  I have spent many hours searching but can't find anything.

They may be installation related but I am not sure.  On my laptop I am running Windows Vista, Python 2.7, pyfpdf 1.7.hg, Explorer 7.0, Chrome 23.0.1271.91 m if that helps.

Q 1: In Explorer, during development, disconnected from the internet,

a) the first run of the report shows a blank page,
b) press ‘back’ and run again it displays as expected,
c) press ‘back’ and run again, the blank page displays and so on

This pattern is fairly consistent but not totally.

Chrome just tells me that it can’t connect to the internet (whether I have the  Chrome PDF Viewer enabled or the Adobe Reader enabled)
Any thoughts?

Q2: When I deployed the app would not run until I made the following changed in fpdf.py at lines 449 and 1326.
                #except IOError as e:  DAVID
                    #if not e.errno == errno.EACCES:
                        #raise  # Not a permission error.
                except:
                    raise
Does this mean that my installation has missed something?

Q3: When deployed, ID displays the following (Chrome displays the same in its own window):

3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœ…–Ko 1 F÷ù Wê¦-Tã÷c™ç"RªJAêz œ††ÌD0 õß×ž ]'ãkØðøÎµÍÅFÂí gÆÁáìb ‹  B2Îaù ×Ë”¤—S"µaV‚ç  Ë |¾ÙÆøÒõp?<Ž‡n ¿ÀòO®™†I$Ž’>1Ê3§Á ÁÄ[ùîw ñ®(ÍÍßUIÍ™õà‚eÊMUwÝº¬cßõ  n‡_; X ¬¦þ0ŠJs p^æ§%ÛË§øð¼- #[ ¶Aä_wŽ¬ž  iK¸ÀêÂ ÐÜÝ‚«Ê:Ç”˜b§æ²˜òÐEìrØ 
›MWñEæbýíÐTF´ªlÕñfðr®ŒiS 1b hï/rUÙtl„• ‰Ï]‹0 ¸2»ªŠ+b„+ mWäª®éÔprÅ0Ÿ•¤+bt+ s²  ¬ Kžÿj Æ 6 #v öî"Wuå–iC¹b˜/ Ò 1Â ¶+r5W  Eum æûr-0²  æT' hÕØ¥ë™SÆ 6 «ïn 4w•àª®éÈ Šr-Ât&(Ê 1Â “ ZÁV}u`ŽêÜ2lù"Fw 2§•‘-*+ÃŒ§”‹°¥Œ ±Å ´Û ¹ª«0yº Í ¸îW0<Â6¾ 
Û ¦ÏŽEÿì¤#ª endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F2 5 0 R /F1 6 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Producer (PyFPDF 1.7 http://pyfpdf.googlecode.com/) /CreationDate (D:20130304000514) >> endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R /OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null] /PageLayout /OneColumn >> endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000851 00000 n 0000001135 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000938 00000 n 0000001034 00000 n 0000001249 00000 n 0000001356 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 8 0 R /Info 7 0 R >> startxref 1459 %%EOF Status: 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q1: I don't think is related with pyfpdf and you don't need to install it: just place the folder in your app..

q2: gae don't permit to write on disk and pyfpdf use the `file()` module for insert images in pdf output. maybe it's your case.

q3: what you see is the pdf code and I see `Content-Type: text/html`. Try to change the Content-Type to `'application/pdf'`

Comment: @DavidFreeman q3: there also is a contentlength 0. Please use the correct content length.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Some comments  1. pyfpdf is in the project's folder  2. My code uses pdf.output(file.pdf, 'D') which should display rather than saving to file(?)  3.My code does not output the content type nor the contentlength. These are generated from pyfpdf.  I am using pyfpdf downloaded from developers.google.com. Even the 4 line example from there produces the above results.  Thanks, David